# foreach for string values, manual list

Tags: string, foreach, stata, manual

How can I create a loop of string values in Stata? A sample of what I am trying to do is mentioned below. I will have many other possible values in the list. I have gone through and made many manual lists, so I want to do it in a similar format to this, where you can look at the code and see the list.

I've found questions on `foreach` and `forval`, but can't seem to find something directly related to `foreach` and string variable values? Am I missing something really simple?

**tried this:**

```
foreach x of

"GREEN BLUE" /// 

"RED ORANGE" ///

 {

replace y = 1 if COLOUR=="`x'" & missing(y)

}
```

**and this:**

```
foreach x of {

"GREEN BLUE" /// 

"RED ORANGE" ///

 {

replace y = 1 if COLOUR=="`x'" & missing(y)

} 

}
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: } is not a valid command name

Answer (score 2):

Your prime source should be the help and manual entry for `foreach`. Either makes clear that there are two distinct syntaxes, starting

`foreach` *index* `in` *list*

`foreach` *index* `of` *keyword* *list_or_where_to_find_it*

You can't use any other syntax (one of your examples puts the list inside the loop) and you can't mix those syntaxes (so using `of` without a keyword is illegal). If Stata's parser is very puzzled at fantasy syntax that you dream up, the error message may not be directly informative.

So, this should work (depending naturally on your dataset, which we can't see)

```
foreach x in "GREEN BLUE" "RED ORANGE" {
    replace y = 1 if COLOUR == "`x'" & missing(y)
}
```

In essence, whatever is not allowed in the syntax diagram at the head of each document is definitely forbidden. Your syntax must match one of the forms.

Meta-tip: Read the Stata documentation before searching the internet.

Comment: IT says "varlist not allowed"

Comment: I can't evaluate that comment. It refers to some code you typed, but I can't diagnose the problem without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Nick's answer, if part of the objective was to include the elements of the list on separate lines for clarity, something like the following, which breaks Nick's first line into four pieces, will do. Again, echoing Nick's advice, the first stop should always be to read the fine material Stata makes available with its `help` command and in the complete documentation supplied as PDFs and available through Stata's `help` menu. With that said,

```
foreach x in ///
"GREEN BLUE" ///
"RED ORANGE" ///
{
replace y = 1 if COLOUR == "`x'" & missing(y)
}
```

Comment: Thank you William and Nick. Where I'm stuck is that after the first line of William's code, I get: { required. Then after each value I get "value" not a valid command name.But what William said about my seeking to have the values in a list (rather than all in one line), is what I am aiming for. Thanks!

Comment: How does `value` relate to this code? To get replies of any worth, you need to tell us **exactly** what you are typing. Note that the `///` comment syntax will not be accepted interactively. It's fine to edit your original question, but better to flag supplements e.g. by EDIT: